# Integration tests with XUnit and .NET Core 2.2 - Can't create WebApplicationFactory client

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, xunit

I make setup for integration tests in .net core 2.2 with xUnit. I have created CustomWebApplciationFactory as in documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Everything work fine till CreatingClient method:

[Exception in setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJoXw.png)

[configuration class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY4J6.png)

[FixtureClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moCHg.png)

Comment: Please copy exception message and the code to the answer, instead of links

Comment: Could you share a simple demo that could reproduce your issue?